# Extract specific value from a string variable in r

Tags: r, string, extract

I have a character variable. I need to extract the information from the `title=""` value. Basically, I need all the values inside of `""` right after the `title=`.

Here is the example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  character = c('mrow&gt;&lt;mn&gt;2&lt;mn&gt;&lt;mi&gt;h&lt;mi&gt;&lt;m title="h+r=2"&gt;&lt;mstyle',
        'mrow&gt;&lt;mn&gt;2&lt;mn&gt;&lt;mi&gt;h&lt;mi&gt;&lt;m title="r+2h=h"&gt;&lt;mstyle&',
        'mrow&gt;&lt;mn&gt;2&lt;mn&gt;&lt;mi&gt;h&lt;mi&gt;&lt;m title="h∙rleft(frac{2h}{2}right)"&gt;&lt;mstyle&gt'))

> df
  id                                                                                                  character
1  1                        mrow&gt;&lt;mn&gt;2&lt;mn&gt;&lt;mi&gt;h&lt;mi&gt;&lt;m title="h+r=2"&gt;&lt;mstyle
2  2                      mrow&gt;&lt;mn&gt;2&lt;mn&gt;&lt;mi&gt;h&lt;mi&gt;&lt;m title="r+2h=h"&gt;&lt;mstyle&
3  3 mrow&gt;&lt;mn&gt;2&lt;mn&gt;&lt;mi&gt;h&lt;mi&gt;&lt;m title="h·rleft(frac{2h}{2}right)"&gt;&lt;mstyle&gt
```

My desired output would be:

```
> df
  id                 character
1  1                     h+r=2
2  2                    r+2h=h
3  3 h·rleft(frac{2h}{2}right)
```

Comment: `within(df, character <- gsub('title="([^"]+)|.', '\\1', df$character))` you don't need additional packages for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(character = sub(".+title=\"(.+)\".+", "\\1", character))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex101 to create a fitting regular expression:

https://regex101.com/r/OFJhnQ/1

Then you can use `str_extract` to obtain the value.

Or you use the `extract` function from tidyr:

```
df %>% tidyr::extract(character, "title", regex="title=\"(.+)\"")
```